# How do i convert a CSV file to <class 'sklearn.utils.Bunch'>?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to load csv file with just two columns, keywords(features or text data) and categories(target) How do I fit this kind of data into scikit learn?

what should I do to convert that csv file to fit into the code?
the code is from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

```
#loading data
# Load the csv file 
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
print(df)
keyword_data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Keyword'])
```

This is how i wanted the above loaded csv file to convert
`categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian','comp.graphics', 'sci.med']`

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True,random_state=42)
```

when I tried to run my csv file in to this

```
twenty_train = keyword_data(subset='train',
                        categories=categories, shuffle=True, 
                         random_state=42)
```

I was getting error like this

```
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 twenty_train = keyword_data(subset='train',
  2                             categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

form me train is `df.['keywords']` which gives all the rows under keyword section of csv file

Comment: It's saying that `keyword_data` is a pandas DataFrame.  What API are you trying to call?  From which module?

Comment: I have a csv file  i was loading it using pandas.

Comment: OK, but what function were you trying to call there?  What function has parameters "subset", "categories", "shuffle", etc?

Comment: I dont think I have any function like that. in place of fetch_20newsgropus I used keywords from csv file I have loaded.

Comment: How can I generate a data into that kind of formats ? so that I can load to some machine learning algorithm and train the data.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?